# Neo4j Cypher: How to optimize a NOT EXISTS Query when cardinality is high

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The below query takes over 1 second & consumer about 7 MB when cardinality b/w users to posts is about 8000 (one user views about 8000 posts). It is difficult to scale this due to high & linearly growing latencies & memory consumption. Is there a possibility to model this differently and/or optimise the query?

**Query**

`PROFILE MATCH (u:User)-[:CREATED]->(p:Post) WHERE NOT (:User{ID: 2})-[:VIEWED]->(p) RETURN p.ID`

**Plan**

```
| Plan      | Statement   | Version      | Planner | Runtime       | Time | DbHits  | Rows | Memory (Bytes) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "PROFILE" | "READ_ONLY" | "CYPHER 4.1" | "COST"  | "INTERPRETED" | 1033 | 3721750 | 10   | 6696240        |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| Operator                     | Details                                       | Estimated Rows | Rows | DB Hits | Cache H/M | Memory (Bytes) | Ordered by     |
+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| +ProduceResults@neo4j        | `p.ID`                                        |           2158 |   10 |       0 |       0/0 |                |                |
| |                            +-----------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| +Projection@neo4j            | p.ID AS `p.ID`                                |           2158 |   10 |      10 |       0/0 |                |                |
| |                            +-----------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| +Filter@neo4j                | u:User                                        |           2158 |   10 |      10 |       0/0 |                |                |
| |                            +-----------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| +Expand(All)@neo4j           | (p)<-[anon_15:CREATED]-(u)                    |           2158 |   10 |      20 |       0/0 |                |                |
| |                            +-----------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| +AntiSemiApply@neo4j         |                                               |           2158 |   10 |       0 |       0/0 |                |                |
| |\                           +-----------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| | +Expand(Into)@neo4j        | (anon_47)-[anon_61:VIEWED]->(p)               |            233 |    0 | 3695819 |       0/0 |        6696240 | anon_47.ID ASC |
| | |                          +-----------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| | +NodeUniqueIndexSeek@neo4j | UNIQUE anon_47:User(ID) WHERE ID = $autoint_0 |           8630 | 8630 |   17260 |       0/0 |                | anon_47.ID ASC |
| |                            +-----------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan@neo4j       | p:Post                                        |           8630 | 8630 |    8631 |       0/0 |                |                |
+------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: So you want ALL the posts ever created that haven't been viewed by user 2? That seems like an odd query to make, is that your real query, or just for the sake of example?

Comment: Yes. I am registering the user to post view in neo4j so that the posts don't repeat for user & user sees only the posts that he hasn't viewed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be improved.

First, let's understand what this is doing.

First, it starts with a NodeByLabelScan. That makes sense, there's no avoiding that.

But then, for every node of the label (the following executes PER ROW!), it matches to user 2, and expands all :VIEWED relationships from user 2 to see if any of them is the post for that particular row.

Can you see why this is inefficient? There are 8630 post nodes according to the PROFILE plan, so user 2 is looked up by index 8630 times, and their :VIEWED relationships are expanded 8630 times. Why 8630 times? Because this is happening per :Post node.

Instead, try this:

```
MATCH (:User{ID: 2})-[:VIEWED]->(viewedPost)
WITH collect(viewedPost) as viewedPosts
MATCH (:User)-[:CREATED]->(p:Post) 
WHERE NOT p IN viewedPosts 
RETURN p.ID
```

This changes things up a bit.

First it matches to user 2's viewed posts (the lookup and expansion is performed only once), then those viewed posts are collected.

Then it will do a label scan, and filter such that the post isn't in the collection of viewed posts.

Comment: Woah. This query helped a lot. The memory consumption decreased by 90% & latencies by over 95%. Thanks for this.